# www site address DNS issue

Tags: dns, dns-servers

Sorry if I leave anything out. I'm new to this side of web-development. I'm a developer who deals mainly with WordPress sites. I took a job working for a company who had an existing site on WordPress. That's all going well, however the previous developer did some interesting things with the DNS on cloudflare. I've set the first line of the record to:
 A example.com points to (the godaddy database IP) TTL automatic
(Next)
A www points to (the same godaddy IP) TTL automatic

The issue is, example.com works fine when you type it in. However the www URL redirects to an entirely different site that I don't recognize. Additionally search engine crawlers can't reach the right site because when you google the company the first result you get is one that says "no information found"

It's been well 4-5 days since I changed the www line of the DNS record.

Also in the record are MX records which I think are for emails, as well as one TXT record that has a google site verification.

How do I fix the DNS so that the www domain redirects properly?

Comment: The www works fine when I just checked.  So it might be caching at your end.

Comment: Others have been unable to reproduce the problem.   Please edit the question if you have additional information about what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`onpacefs.com` currently has CloudFlare nameservers (`igor` and `becky`) and `www`resolves to IP addresses `104.18.51.170`, `104.18.50.170`, `2400:cb00:2048:1::6812:32aa` and `2400:cb00:2048:1::6812:33aa`.

In my browser `http://www.onpacefs.com` and `https://www.onpacefs.com` both redirect to `http://onpacefs.com/` which loads successfully.

`onpacefs.com` resolves to the same 4 IP addresses.

You have no DNS configuration errors: http://dnsviz.net/d/onpacefs.com/Wmj82w/dnssec/

So I fail to see your problem. You should give more details on what you see exactly (both on the DNS and HTTP level), what you have changed (from what value to what value) and what you expect.
(I do not know what you mean by "*however the previous developer did some interesting things with the DNS on cloudflare*")

Comment: When I type in www.onpacefs.com I'm sent to https://www.shop-ware.cf/. This only happens on my work computer, on chrome... Isn't that strange, must be cached or something. On Firefox all is well. As for the search engine not finding information on the site, I forgot the previous developer had put a "do not index" on the site during development. A simple check box fixed that. Haha well, that was easy. Thanks guys!

Comment: Do you reproduce with a fresh install/profile of Chrome?